# how do I select elements of same div as the button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>
```

This is my HTML Code. I have a Javascript code that executes when someone click on the link with class "download-button"

The code looks something like this

```
$(".download-button").click(function(event){
    document.querySelector('.download-progress-container').style.display = 'none';
});
```

When I click on the `download-button` link of the second `td` element, the first `td` element `download-progress-container` hides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to hide clicked element

```js
$(".download-button").click(function(event){

  var _t = $(this);
  
    _t.parents('td').find('.download-progress-container').hide();
    //document.querySelector('.download-button').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>
<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>

<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Why not just `$(this).hide()` ?

Comment: can use direct `$(this).hide()`, i just prefer to store in a variable in further operation related to selected element. Something like success of ajax call.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I don't want to hide `download-button`, but other elements. Please see the question again, reallly sorry.

Comment: Hey, everything is running as expected. But `_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').click();` is not working

Comment: then try `trigger('click')`

Comment: `_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').trigger('click');` is also not working. I just want to click the button

Comment: when you use `t.parents('td').find('.save-file').trigger('click');` ??

Comment: Actually, I am showing download progress bar within the website using XHR. After the site downloads the file using Ajax, clicking on `.save-file` button, saves the file in the user's browser. So on click, it downloads the file.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.save-file').click();` works but  not as expected. Note that save-file display is none.

Comment: Creating, also `_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').attr('download', fileName);` do not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197320/discussion-between-devsi-odedra-and-john-doe).

Comment: Hey, please check the message

Answer (score 2):

Get the common parent  element and then find the element within it to hide.

```
$(".download-button").click(function(event){
   // prevent default click event action
   event.preventDefault();
   // get the td ancestor and get element within that td
   $(this).closest('.name').find('.download-progress-container').hide();
});
```

```js
$(".download-button").click(function(event) {
  // prevent default click event action
  event.preventDefault();
  // get the td ancestor and get element within that td
  $(this).closest('.name').find('.download-progress-container').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">
      <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
          <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
      </div>
      <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
    </td>
    <td class="name">
      <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
          <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
      </div>
      <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
    </td>

    <td class="name">
      <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
          <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
      </div>
      <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to hide all `.download-progress-container` descendants of the `.parent()` of the download button being clicked. You can achieve that with the following:

```
$(".download-button").click(function(event) {

   /* Prevent default click action behavior */
   event.preventDefault();

   /* Hide the progress container that is a descendant of the same
   anscestor of the download button being clicked */
   $('.download-progress-container', $(this).parent()).hide();
});
```

Here's a working snippet (yellow blocks show progress element):

```js
$(".download-button").click(function(event) {

  /* Prevent default click action behavior */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* Hide the progress container that is a descendant of the same
  anscestor of the download button being clicked */
  $('.download-progress-container', $(this).parent()).hide();
});
```

```css
.download-progress {
  background:yellow;
  height:1rem;
  width:2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>
<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>

<td class="name">
    <div class="download-ui-container">
        <div class="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div class="download-progress-container">
            <div class="download-progress"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
    <a href="abc.mp4" class="download-button">abc.mp4</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code with following.

**Replace**

```
$(".download-button").click(function(event){
    document.querySelector('.download-button').style.display = 'none';
});
```

**With**

```
$(".download-button").click(function(event){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. I want to hide download-progress-container not download-button. I edited the question